# how to skip XSD:type while unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

i received the xml

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns1:paymentResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:Brifastservice">
    <return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="tns:paymentAccount_CT_Result">
        <message xsi:type="xsd:string">[ERROR] Reference Number Same </message>
        <status xsi:type="xsd:string">2007</status>
    </return>
 </ns1:paymentResponse>
```

i want to unmarshal it , i am using below code

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PaymentResponse.class);
Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader resRreader = new StringReader(res);

final SAXParserFactory sax = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
sax.setNamespaceAware(true);
final XMLReader reader = sax.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
final Source er = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(resRreader));

PaymentResponse response = (PaymentResponse)um.unmarshal(er);
return response.getReturnResponse().getMessage();
```

but I got the exception

> prefix xsd is not bound to a namespace

If I use

```
sax.setNamespaceAware(false);
```

then I get

> ```
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ns1:paymentResponse").
>   Expected elements are <{urn:someService}paymentResponse>
> ```

please suggest how to unmarshal? I have package info

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "urn:someService",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML document uses XSI to declare the XSD type of the elements, but the XSD namespace is not defined anywhere inside this document.

A quick and dirty solution would be to modify the string with the received XML document and forcefully add a `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` declaration in the root element before it is parsed.

The proper soluction is to create a custom ContentHandler that intercepts the `startDocument`, `endDocument`, `startPrefixMapping` and `endPrefixMapping` events and makes uses of `NamespaceSupport` object to keep track of the declared namespaced and also inject the missing XSD namespace. An example of this (minus the injected namespace) can be found in the chapter *Receiving Namespace Mappings* of *Processing XML with Java*, available online at http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch06s09.html.